# Some clarification about arrays for a project

Tags: c#, arrays, textbox

Or someone to explain how to do this or direct me to some resources. Here's the assignment info:

dataCaptured: integer array - This field will store a history of a limited set of recently captured measurements. Once the array is full, the class should start overwriting the oldest elements while continuing to record the newest captures. (You may need some helper fields/variables to go with this one).

mostRecentMeasure: integer - This field will store the most recent measurement captured for convenience of display.

GetRawData. Return the contents of the dataCapturedarray. Which element is the oldest one in your history? Do you need to manipulate these values? How will they be presented to the user?

Add a button to display the measurement history (GetRawData). Where/how will you display this list? What did you make GetRawData() return? Does the list start with the oldest value collected? What happens when your history array fills up and older values are overwritten? What happens when your history has not been filled up yet? Does "0" count as an actual history entry? Does your history display the units in which the data was collected?

So, I want to pass the entire array to a Textbox? How do I do that? Atm, I do have the device up and running and I have a textbox ready for the array, I think. Can someone direct me to  some articles on where to pass this information? Thanks for any help.

currently i have:

```
private double[] dataCaptured;
   public double[] GetRawData()
        {
            return dataCaptured;
        }
```

very little :(

Comment: Here are a few keywords for you to search: queue, stack, circular buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to do your homework for you, so this isn't really an answer; it's more of a tutorial.

First, the problem you have been assigned is a common one.  Consider some kind of chemical process.  You build a system that periodically measures some attribute of the system (say temperature).  Depending on the nature of the process, you may measure it every 200 milliseconds, every 2 seconds, every 2 minutes, whatever.  But, you are going to do that forever.  You want to keep the data for some time, but not forever - memory is cheap these days, but not that cheap.

So you decide to keep the last N measurements.  You can keep that in an N-element array. When you get the first measurement, you put it in the 0-element of the array, the second in the 1-element, and so on.  When you get to the Nth measurement, you stick it in the last element.  But, with the (N+1)th element, you have a problem.  The solution is to put it in the 0-element of the array.  The next one goes into the 1-element of the array, and so on.

At that point, you need some bookkeeping.  You need to track where you put the most recent element.  You also need to keep track of where the oldest element is.  You also need a way to get all the measurements in some soft of time order.

This is a circular buffer.  The reason it's *circular* is because you count 0, 1, 2...N-1, N, 0, 1, 2 and so on, around and around forever.

When you first start filling the buffer with measurements, the oldest is in element-0, and the most recent is wherever you put the last measurement.  It continues like that until you have filled the buffer.  Once you do that, then the oldest is no longer at 0, it's at the element *logically after* the most recent one (which is either the next element, or, if you are at the end of buffer, at the 0 position).

You could track the oldest and the newest indexes in the array/buffer.  An easier way is to just track whether you are in the initial *haven't-filled-buffer-yet* phase (a boolean) and the latest index.  The oldest is either index 0 (if you haven't filled buffer yet) or the one logically after the newest one.  The bookkeeping is a little easier that way.

To do this, you need a way to find the next logical index in the buffer (either *index+1* or *0* if you've hit the end of the buffer).  You also need a way to get all the data (start at the index logically after the current entry, and then get the next N logical entries).

By the way, I'd use `float` rather than `double` to track my measurement.  In general, measurements have enough error in themselves that the extra precision offered by `double` is of no use.  By halving the data size, you can make your buffer twice as long (this, by the way, is a consideration in a measurement and control system).

For your measurement source, I'd initially use a number generator that starts at `1.0f` to start and just increments by `1.0f` every cycle.  It will make debugging much simpler.

```
private float tempValue = 1.0f;
private float GetNextValue()
{
    tempValue += 1.0f;
    return tempValue;
}
```

Once you do this for real, you may want random numbers, something like:

```
private readonly Random _random = new Random();
private const float MinValue = 4.0f;
private const float MaxValue = 20.0f;
private float GetNextValue()
{
    var nextRandom = _random.NextDouble();
    var nextValue = (float) ((MaxValue - MinValue) * nextRandom + MinValue);
    return nextValue;
}
```

By the way, the choice of 4.0 and 20.0 is intentional - google for "4 20 measurement".

If you want to get fancy, generate a random number stream and run it through a smoothing filter (but that gets more complicated).

You asked about how to get all the values into a single text box.  This should do the trick:

```
// concatenate a collection of float values (rendered with one decimal point)
// into a string (with some spaces separating the values)
private string FormatValuesAsString(IEnumerable<float> values)
{
    var buffer = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var val in values)
    {
        buffer.Append($"{val:F1}  ");
    }

    return buffer.ToString();
}
```

An `IEnumerable<float>` represents a collection of `float` values.  An array of floats implements that interface, as does just about every other collection of floats (which means you can put an array in for that parameter (`FormatValuesAsString(myArray)`).  You can also create a function that dynamically generates values (look up `yield return`).  The `FormatValuesAsString` function will return a string you can shove into a text box.  If you do that on each calculation cycle, you'll see your values shift through the text box.

You will get to know the debugger very well doing this exercise.  It is ***very*** hard to get this right in the first one, or two, or three, or... tries (you'll learn why programmers curse *off-by-one* errors).  Don't give up.  It's a good assignment.

*Finally, if you get confused, you can post questions as comments to this *answer* (within reason).  Tag me (to make sure I see them).*